# mykernel.iso execution error in my Operating System

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, linker, operating-system

I am currently working on my Operating System and my problem is regarding mykernel.iso which I created from MakeFile. My distro is Kali Linux and the issue I am having is regarding boot.
In my directory I have `Makefile`,`kernel.cpp`,`kernel.o`,`linker.d`,`loader.o`,`loader.s`,`types.h`,`mykernel.o`,`mykernel.iso`. When I boot mykernel.iso using VirtualBox, I get an error

> Fatal! Could not read from the boot medium. System Halted!

(Also mykernel.iso should be 4 mb,mine is 340 kb)

Following is the code:

> Makefile:

```
GCCPARAMS = -m32 -fno-use-cxa-atexit -nostdlib -fno-builtin -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-leading-underscore
ASPARAMS = --32
LDPARAMS = -melf_i386

objects = loader.o kernel.o



%.o: %.cpp
    gcc $(GCCPARAMS) -c -o $@ $<

%.o: %.s
    as $(ASPARAMS) -o $@ $<

mykernel.bin: linker.ld $(objects)
    ld $(LDPARAMS) -T $< -o $@ $(objects)

mykernel.iso: mykernel.bin
    mkdir iso
    mkdir iso/boot
    mkdir iso/boot/grub
    cp mykernel.bin iso/boot/mykernel.bin
    echo 'set timeout=0'                      > iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
    echo 'set default=0'                     >> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
    echo ''                                  >> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
    echo 'menuentry "My Operating System" {' >> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
    echo '  multiboot /boot/mykernel.bin'    >> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
    echo '  boot'                            >> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
    echo '}'                                 >> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
    grub-mkrescue --output=mykernel.iso iso
    rm -rf iso

run: mykernel.iso
    (killall VirtualBox && sleep 1) || true
    VirtualBox --startvm 'My Operating System' &

install: mykernel.bin
    sudo cp $< /boot/mykernel.bin
```

---

kernel.cpp:

```
#include "types.h"

void printf(char* str)
{
    static uint16_t* VideoMemory = (uint16_t*)0xb8000;

    for(int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i)
        VideoMemory[i] = (VideoMemory[i] & 0xFF00) | str[i];
}



typedef void (*constructor)();
extern "C" constructor start_ctors;
extern "C" constructor end_ctors;
extern "C" void callConstructors()
{
    for(constructor* i = &start_ctors; i != &end_ctors; i++)
        (*i)();
}



extern "C" void kernelMain(const void* multiboot_structure, uint32_t /*multiboot_magic*/)
{
    printf("Welcome To My Operating System");

    while(1);
}
```

Any Suggestions amigos?

Comment: install newest version for iso file generating sudo install xorriso if you are in ubuntu

Comment: Thanks a lot @JerryChen. Successfully nailed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are on Kali Distro. Switching to Ubuntu and applying

```
sudo apt-get install xorriso
```

should work like a charm son.